# i have a map variable i need to use that to draw a pie chart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

```
 var map = new object();

 var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) { return d ;} );

 var arcs =group.selectAll(".arc").data(pie(JSON.parse(map))) 
           .enter().append("g")
           .attr("class","arc");
 arcs.append("path")
 .attr("d",arc)
 .attr("fill" , function (d) { return color(d.map ); });

 arcs.append("text")
 .attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" +arc.centroid(d)+       
 ")";})
 .attr("text-anchor","middle")
 .attr("font-size","1.5em")
 .text(function(d){ return d.data; });

 arcs.append("text")
    .attr("dx", function(d){return -100;})
 .attr("dy", function(d){return 9;})
    .text(function(d){return totalmails+" mails in last 7days";})
.attr("font-size","1.5em")
.attr("fill","black");
```

my map variable contains the following data..

```
 Object {URGENT: 10, NORMAL: 20, FYI: 30}...
```

I need to use this to draw pie chart. Here i have tried using json parse to draw the pie. so please suggest how to draw pie for the json data before using json i tried to draw using just an array of numbers.Now i need to draw using the json, which is in this form `Object {URGENT: 10, NORMAL: 20, FYI: 30}`,need to plot for the keys urgent , normal, FYI

Answer (score 0):

Actually I can't see any JSON data in your code. The `map` variable is just an object. A JSON with your data would look like the following string:

```
var map = '{"URGEND":10,"NORMAL":20,"FYI":10}';
```

If there is the option to change your JSON, a better layout for piecharts would be:

```
var map = '[{"name":"URGEND","value":10},{"name":"NORMAL","value":20},{"name":"FYI","value":10}]';
```

This way you could use a `layout.pie` with a value function of:

```
.value(function(d){return d.value;})
```

And the `.text()` function you could use this way:

```
.text(function(d){ return d.name; })
```

If there is still something unclear to you, maybe you should post more of your code, like the functions `arc` and `color`